# OOP real world example

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance

I have a basic shopping cart model with products that are based on data from a database with columns of productID, productName,Price,Stock. I then have a item class which represents the item a consumer chooses to order with the productID,ProductName,Price. I then have the itemOrder class which references the item with productID,ProductName,Price, and the quantity with a getPrice(). There is then a Cart class which holds the itemOrder's and defines methods for adding and deleting an itemOrder.

In any of these classes or in a typical shopping cart system, where do OOP techniques come into play.

```
public class Product
{
    public int productID { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    ...
 }
}

public class Item : Product
{

}

public class ItemOrder : Item
{
    public int itemQuantity { get; set; }
    public double getPrice(int quantity, double price)
    {
        return price = price * quantity;
    }

}
public class Cart
{

}
```

Comment: This question more appropriate when you talk about how to orchestrate interaction between processes using these objects. You will probably need to check stock on a List of Items and pay for a List of Items and then send confirmation that a List of Items has been shipped and even add the ability to refund a List of Items. The plain objects you have listed are just data structures to hold information that can be passed around using a standard convention. OO and Interfaces usually come into play when controlling access to and applying processing to your objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance is not required for OOP (see, e.g., [discussion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ConfusionAboutInheritance)).  If your classes are hiding internal details from the world, presenting a consistent interface that clients can't use to break the objects, and each doing a single job well, you have OOP (in my personal opinion).

Only use inheritance if the relationship between two classes meets the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): Child inherits from Parent if and *only if* Child is a Parent.  For example, when you implement an interface, the new class is that interface, as far as calling code is concerned.

An item, a product, and an order are three different things, and none of them is interchangeable with the others.  All three classes should exist, but they should not be related by inheritance.  Carts, Items, and Orders can refer to Products and to each other by references or containment rather than by inheritance.